# where windows 10 the "task scheduler" store log file?

Tags: windows, task, scheduled-tasks, logfile

I would simply view the log file of my "task scheduler".
I have "windows 10 pro"

I thought it was into the file "C:\Windows\Tasks\SchedLgU.txt" but I haven't that file

someone help?

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To view the logs in Windows 10, start Event Viewer (eventvwr.msc) and navigate to "Applications and Services Logs" / Microsoft / Windows / TaskScheduler.

The corresponding files are in C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler*.EVTX.